# What does this character mean? 

Tags: meaning, character-identification

What does this mean: ?
It's in traditional form, because that is what appeared when I copied and pasted an emoji from Gmail into Gchat. I don't have a traditional dictionary, so I looked up what I figured should be the simplified version: 艹 on top of 领. Can anyone help me?

谢谢！

Comment: Could you provide a picture? It doesn't render in my browser, and when cutting and pasting into Unihan and such, it resolves to the codepoint U+F604, which is "not in unihan" and "not a valid unicode character".

Comment: Figured it might be a SunmanPUA character, but doesn't seem like it...I guess someone could copy this into gChat and see for themselves, or look up what PUA google uses for it's junk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it `䕘` ?

[image]

> 《集韻》同苓。又良郢切，音領。草名

means

According to [Jiyun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiyun), same as `苓`. And pronounced as `良郢切`, i.e. `領`. (`良郢切` means the combination of the initial consonant of `良` (liang) and the vowel of `郢` (ying), i.e. `l` + `ing` = `ling`. It's grass' name.

http://www.zdic.net/z/12/kx/4558.htm

And

> 苓
> líng ㄌㄧㄥˊ
>
> 1. 指“茯苓”。
> 　2. 古书上说的一种植物。
> 　3. 古同“零”，零落。

means

1. poria cocos
2. a kind of plant in ancient books
3. same as 零, withered and fallen

Comment: That is the character, but I'm afraid the site you linked to is beyond my level of Chinese. Presumably "同苓" means that it's the same meaning as "苓," and "音領" means that it sounds like "領" (or am I wrong?). What do "《集韻》... 又良郢切 ... 草名" mean? Does "草名" refer to the grass radical? Thank you!

Comment: @MissMonicaE `集韻` is an ancient book. I've added some explanations.

Comment: The real question, though, is: in what PUA font is 䕘 U+F604?

Comment: @user3306356 Sorry I have not idea about that..